# Add values by field SQL Oracle SUM( )

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

```
Supervisor   TalkTime  HoldTime   CallsHandle
    Agent1     400        20          5
    Agent1     360        30          2
    Agent1     200        21          5
    Agent2     150        15          4
    Agent2     120        10          5
```

I need to add the Talktime per agent. **Agent1 = *960* & Agent2 = *270***
On Oracle BI SQL how do I add all the TalkTime per agent to display in the new field. I have about 250 agents on the table. The i have to do the followig formula too: **AHT = (TalkTime + HoldTime)/CallsHandle**

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple group by statement.  It is covered in every introduction to SQL course or book

```
SELECT supervisor, SUM(TalkTime+HoldTime) / SUM(CallsHandle) AS AHT
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Supervisor
```

Comment: I understand this procedure. I want to do it like a calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

```
select supervisor,sum(talktime),sum(holdtime),sum(callshandle),SUM(talktime+holdtime) / SUM(callshandle) as AHT
from table_name
group by supervisor
```

Answer (score 0):

To display details and sums best way is to use function `sum()` in analytic version:

```
select supervisor, talktime, holdtime, 
    sum(TalkTime) over (partition by supervisor) talk_sum,
    sum((TalkTime + HoldTime)/CallsHandle) over (partition by supervisor) AHT
  from test
  order by supervisor;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb5e9/1)

```
SUPERVISOR   TALKTIME   HOLDTIME   TALK_SUM        AHT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Agent1            400         20        960      323,2 
Agent1            360         30        960      323,2 
Agent1            200         21        960      323,2 
Agent2            150         15        270      67,25 
Agent2            120         10        270      67,25
```

Answer (score 0):

As from your query i understand that you want to just add this AHT in your BI report there is no need to insert this details in other table. Please find the query as below.

Query.

```
select SUPERVISOR,SUM(TALKTIME) AS Total_TalkTime
,SUM(HOLDTIME) as Total_HoldTime
,SUM(AHT) as AHT 
from 
(select Supervisor,TalkTime,HoldTime,CallsHandle
,(TalkTime+HoldTime)\CallsHandle AS AHT FROM TABLENAME) 
group by SUPERVISOR;
```